# Generating strings dynamically in Python

Tags: python, strings

I'm generating a URL (in string) that depends on 3 optional parameters, `file`, `user` and `active`.

From a base url: `/hey` I want to generate the endpoint, this means:

- If `file` is specificied, my desired output would is: `/hey?file=example`
- If `file` and `user` is specified, my desired output is: `/hey?file=example&user=boo`
- If `user` and `active` are specified, my desired output is: `/hey?user=boo&active=1`
- If no optional parameters are specified, my desired output is: `/hey`
- and so on with all the combinations...

My code, which is working correctly, is as follows (change the `None`'s at the top if you want to test it):

```
file = None
user = None
active = 1

ep = "/hey"
isFirst = True

if file:
  if isFirst:
    ep+= "?file=" + file;
    isFirst = False;
  else: ep += "&file=" + file;

if user:
  if isFirst:
    ep+= "?user=" + user;
    isFirst = False;
  else: ep += "&user=" + user;

if active:
  if isFirst:
    ep+= "?active=" + str(active);
    isFirst = False;
  else: ep += "&active=" + str(active);

print ep
```

Can someone give me *a more python implementation* for this? I can't use modules as `requests`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lose the `;`. makes python look ugly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most Pythonic version of this depends a bit on what you do with that URL afterwards. If you are using the `requests` module (which you probably should), this is already built-in by [specifying the `params` keyword](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
import requests

URL = "https://example.com/hey"

r1 = requests.get(URL, params={"file": "example"})
print(r1.url)
# https://example.com/hey?file=example

r2 = requests.get(URL, params={"file": "example", "user": "boo"})
print(r2.url)
# https://example.com/hey?file=example&user=boo

r3 = requests.get(URL, params={"user": "boo", "active": 1})
print(r3.url)
# https://example.com/hey?user=boo&active=1

r4 = requests.get(URL, params={})
print(r4.url)
# https://example.com/hey
```

---

If you do need a pure Python solution without any imports, this is what I would do:

```
def get_url(base_url, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs:
        return base_url
    params = "&".join(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items())
    return base_url + "?" + params
```

Of course this does not urlencode the  keys and values and may therefore be a security risk or fail unexpectedly, but neither does your code.

Example usage:

```
print(get_url("/hey", file="example"))
# /hey?file=example

print(get_url("/hey", file="example", user="boo"))
# /hey?file=example&user=boo

print(get_url("/hey", user="boo", active=1))
# /hey?user=boo&active=1

print(get_url("/hey"))
# /hey
```

Comment: Due to the implementation of the rest of the code, I need to do it everything without any _requests_ module, just improving the code I posted using strings.

Comment: Can you please give me a simple example of how to use the `get_url` function please? The `**kwargs` part is a bit hard for me to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Avión: Just did. It captures all keyword arguments you pass to the function into one dictionary.

Comment: Your code is good for illustrative purposes but it fails to URLencode the parameters and is therefore a potential security risk.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True, which is why I would recommend using the already existing stuff that is in `requests` (first part of my answer) or in `urllib` (like in Matthias answer) for production.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Added a short disclaimer regarding that.

Comment: It's not just that it's a security risk, it's also that if you have `&` in one of the values, it will fail to send the correct value (and most likely fail in general, unless there's also another `=` in the values).

Comment: @ChatterOne True, but I still stand by my answer. In any real context you can use modules like `request` (it is in the standard library after all) and you should. If however you need to do it yourself, this is a shortened and IMO more pythonic version of the OPs code. It sounds like it is an assignment where things like sanitized/only simple input is often guaranteed. If it is not, then the OPs code does not work as intended either, which would make the question off topic here.

Comment: @ChatterOne Amended the disclaimer to say that it also may fail unexpectedly because of the lack of urlencoding.

Answer (score 18):

You're pretty much reinventing [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode


def prepare_query_string(**kwargs):
    return urlencode([(key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items() if value is not None])
```

Usage being:

```
>>> prepare_query_string(active=1)
'active=1'
>>> prepare_query_string(active=1, user=None)
'active=1'
>>> prepare_query_string(active=1, user='bob')
'active=1&user=bob'
>>> prepare_query_string(file='foo.tar.gz', user='bob')
'file=foo.tar.gz&user=bob'
>>> prepare_query_string(file='foo.tar.gz', user='bob', active=None)
'file=foo.tar.gz&user=bob'
>>> prepare_query_string(file='foo.tar.gz', user='bob', active=1)
'file=foo.tar.gz&user=bob&active=1'
```